# Can I hide the menubar/tray on the secondary monitor in Natty?

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors

In Maverick the topmost tray used to be shown only on the primary monitor, and I liked that better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you currently can't.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/883478